# Kotlin Creating a generic function that accepts any enum that implements an interface

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums

Currently I have multiple enums each with a `userFriendly : string`, e.g.

```
enum class TestGroup(val userFriendly: String) {
    A("A"),
    B("B")
}
```

For each enum I now have a separate function transforming them to a class SelectField:

```
class SelectField(
    val value: String, /** The value which gets submitted e.g. a UUID or other identifier */
    val text: String /** The human-friendly label e.g. the name of an organisation */
)

fun transformTestGroups(testGroups: Array<TestGroup>): List<SelectField> =
        testGroups.map {
            SelectField(
                value = it.name,
                text = it.userFriendly
            )
        }
```

I found that enums could implement an interface:

```
interface UserFriendly {
    val userFriendly: String
}
enum class TestGroup(override val userFriendly: String) : UserFriendly {
    A("A"),
    B("B")
}
```

However, I don't know how to make a `genericTransform(values:Array<Enum<UserFriendly>>):List<SelectField>`. Is this possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in Kotlin are mutable and hence [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). That's a fancy way of saying that an `Array<Int>` is *not* an `Array<Any>`. The reason for that is: If we could cast `x: Array<Int>` up to `Array<Any>`, then we could write `x[0] = "ABC"`, since `"ABC"` is a valid `Any`, and now `x` would contain a value that is not an integer.

So simply using the supertype won't work here. But generics will. Specifically, we'll use the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to require that our generic argument be an enum *and* a `UserFriendly`.

```
fun<T> transformTestGroups(testGroups: Array<T>): List<SelectField>
  where T: UserFriendly,
        T: Enum<T> =
    // Same implementation as before :)
    testGroups.map {
      SelectField(
        value = it.name,
        text = it.userFriendly
      )
    }
```

Complete runnable example:

```
interface UserFriendly {
  val userFriendly: String
}

enum class TestGroup(override val userFriendly: String): UserFriendly {
  A("A"),
  B("B")
}

data class SelectField(
  val value: String,
  val text: String
)

fun<T> transformTestGroups(testGroups: Array<T>): List<SelectField>
  where T: UserFriendly,
        T: Enum<T> =
    testGroups.map {
      SelectField(
        value = it.name,
        text = it.userFriendly
      )
    }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(transformTestGroups(arrayOf(TestGroup.A, TestGroup.B)))
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHbaoQwEH33KwafElj8ANkVFLr7UujD2g8IOm5DY5TJuO1S9tttvFTtbSBkOEnOZfLasNG277VlpEoVCM8O6UgabWlu8BEAXJWBbgPGcGbS9hLcgwBtV0NhlHOQo@MTNV0rmisS6RL/fSnj3yqpCNNQ7nyXiTAL5cBeKlYz@xkNFnzUaEoxe/Krwy/K3QwyvvNiUAZB1dl9ngCTsq5qqF5cOsFLG0NKpG7@onf2qB3vN3KJZ357QULIv9seJKfyBw9@EIPQYQRX6qhW7ZhvqB8hphpjwAE0R1bVuLIOUSZ8O8P5WI77fQwItdJWKLosQab8iRyVW9@zseKvGajh@lMlFihKd@tPRpmU/iP6/hM)

Comment: This is perfect! I actually figured out that if you added `val name: String` to `UserFriendly` it also works, because `enum` implicitly have that `name`, but I think you way is nicer. Thanks!